# Mongoose how to push to array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hi I'm stuck with this problem. I just gotta clear and update my array in mongoose here's my all router code

```
router.get("/update", (req, res, next) => {
    //update edilcek obje bulunur
    const promise = Dictionary.findByIdAndUpdate(
        "5fece9e86f500741f0b6bba4"
        , { $set: { dict: [] } },
        
        { new: true }
    );
 
    var texts = ["Certain", "Deduce", "Marauders", "Favour"];
 
    promise.then((dictData) => {
        
        texts.forEach(element => {
            translatte(element, { to: 'fr' }).then(res => {
                //i can get values hereby
                console.log("Word: "+element+ " Translate: " + res.text);
                 var metn=element;
                 var cev=res.text;
                 //but not pushing
                dictData.dict.push({ text: metn, translated_text: cev });
            });
            
        });
            //this 2 line pushs data 
        dictData.dict.push({ text: "element2", translated_text: "res.tex2" });
        dictData.dict.push({ text: "element3", translated_text: "res.tex3" });
        dictData.name="3423asd";
        dictData.save().then(()=>{
            console.log("update ");
        }).catch(err=>{
            console.log("save error");
            console.log(err);
        });
    }).catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
    });


    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });

});


module.exports = router;
```

In mongo atlas all I can get this

[image: The last 2 push]
Console log works fine

Word : "ssss" Translate:"sss"

Basicly i cant fill the array. Where is the problem. Thank you

The new error
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that your `translatte` function is asynchronous and it's `then` block runs after all your synchronous statements are already executed and your DB is already updated.

And the other problem is that you're using `finByIdAndUpdate` and `save` methods simultaneously.

You can solve your problem by changing the `findByIdAndUpdate` to `findById` and using an `async` request handler so you can `await` for all your `translatte` functions in the for loop to be executed and then update the document and send the response back.

```
router.get("/update", async (req, res, next) => {
  const dictData = await Dictionary.findById("5fece9e86f500741f0b6bba4").exec();
  dictData.dict = [];
  var texts = ["Certain", "Deduce", "Marauders", "Favour"];
  for (const element of texts) {
    const res = await translatte(element, { to: "fr" });
    var metn = element;
    var cev = res.text;
    dictData.dict.push({ text: metn, translated_text: cev });
  }
  dictData.dict.push({ text: "element2", translated_text: "res.tex2" });
  dictData.dict.push({ text: "element3", translated_text: "res.tex3" });
  dictData.name = "3423asd";
  const result = await dictData.save();
  console.log("updated", result);
  return res.render("index", { title: "Express" });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: But it says  
save error
ParallelSaveError: Can't save() the same doc multiple times in parallel. Document: 5fece9e86f500741f0b6bba4

Comment: update 
save error
TypeError: res.render is not a function
    at C:\Users\avcii\Desktop\RN APPS\simpledictionary\server\routes\dictionary.js:89:21
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)

Comment: edited the answer. let me know if there are still problems. do you want to empty the dict before updating it?

Comment: so the above edited code should have solved you're problem. haven't it?

Comment: I just work for first element then says 
save error
ParallelSaveError: Can't save() the same doc multiple times in parallel. Document: 5fece9e86f500741f0b6bba4
    at model.Model.save

Comment: I changed the code. have you reviewed my answer and updated your code? refresh and read the answer again please.

Comment: I wish but as i said it works for first element then gives error. I copied it at all and pasted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226711/discussion-between-abbas-and-mongoman).

Comment: Exactly thank you for your answer, there was a little mistake. Just gotta findById then update . Thank you again, have a good day

Comment: You're welcome! I'm so glad I could help!